# Нужна ли запятая перед сравнительным определением

Tags: пунктуация

"Защита от ОЗЗ на кабельной разделке и на шинах 2СШ осуществля-ется первой ступенью защиты РЗ-2а с действием на отключение секционно-го выключателя с выдержкой времени(,) большей на ступень селективности максимальной выдержки времени отходящих присоединений 2СШ".

Благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна:

*Защита от ОЗЗ на кабельной разделке и на шинах 2СШ осуществляется-ется первой ступенью защиты РЗ-2а с действием на отключение секционного выключателя с выдержкой времени, **большей на ступень селективности максимальной выдержки времени отходящих присоединений 2СШ.***

Текст сложно понимается, и я бы написала так:

*...действием на отключение секционного выключателя с выдержкой времени, **большей  максимальной выдержки** времени отходящих присоединений 2СШ **на ступень селективности**.*

**Пояснение**

***Больший*** — это обычное прилагательное (не степень сравнения). **Сравнение** заложено в его лексическом значении. Поэтому определительный оборот обособляется по общим правилам в позиции **после определяемого** слова.

**[Словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=48)**

БОЛЬШИЙ, сравн., превосх. ст., кратк. ф. нет, кач., IV е.
● 1.0. Такой, к-рый **характеризуется более высокими количественными показателями, параметрами.**   Ант. <меньший>. В большей степени. Большая часть имущества. Большую часть пути мы прошли пешком. Для этого шоу нужна девушка большего роста, вы недостаточно высоки. Я думала, что у тебя квартира большей площади. Роман оказался большего объёма, чем заказывало издательство. Да, мы думали, что здесь б. выбор товаров, а оказалось …

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!